# Not able find user in userinformation list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I am using one list and it has one person field configured for "All Users".

So when i type some email ID in that person field, it is getting user and it works well.

But when i wants to add new record through client object model, some users are not available in UserinformationList in c# and Javascript as well.

Here is the code which i am trying to get all users list.

```
ClientContext clientContext1 = new ClientContext(SiteUrl);
clientContext1.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
UserCollection usrdd = clientContext1.Web.SiteUsers;
clientContext1.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

A user entry is only present in that list if it's added to anything within that site collection (a group, a list, a web, etc.).

You can use [SPWeb.EnsureUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser(v=office.15).aspx) or [SP.Web.ensureUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245233(v=office.15).aspx) to make sure the entry is available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how can i add a first time user to person field? Please help me

Comment: `ensureUser` will return a [SP.User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246835(v=office.15).aspx). You can use that for your field.

Comment: Got it michael.. can i get user by email Id instead logon name?

Comment: If it's SharePoint Online e-mail will be the same as logon name